# Prolog - determine amount of duplicates in list and turn the amount into an exponent

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates, exponent

I want to calculate the amount of duplicates and delete them, and print the amount of duplicates as an exponent. Non-duplicates remain the same. For example:

```
exponent([2, 2, 3, 5, 5], X).
X = [2^2, 3, 5^2]
```

and

```
exponent([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], X).
X = [2^7]
```

Comment: What is not working in your current approach?

Comment: This is a bit like 'run length encoding' ...

Comment: what output do you expect for `[2, 2, 3, 5, 5,2,2]`??

Comment: @coder: `[2^2, 3, 5^2, 2^2]` given I understand it correctly, it is thus a compression where you each time specify "this value is repeated n times".

Comment: @coder [2^4, 3, 5] but the numbers in the list are only incrementing so all 2's are right after each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to arrange for by "eating" through your list and building the result in the characteristically Prologish top-down manner at the same time:

```erlang
exponent( [X | XS], Ex ):-
    exponent( 1, X, XS, Ex ).
```

Wait, what? We haven't said anything specific yet... Except that we've seen *one* `X` by now. Then,

```erlang
exponent( I, X, [Y | XS], Ex ):-
    (   X =:= Y 
    ->  I1 is ...., 
        exponent(I1, X, XS, Ex)    % right? we go on 'eating up' the input
    ;
        Ex = [ (I,X) | Ex2 ],      % intentionally 'wrong' output
        exponent( 1, ........ )
    ).
```

See?

Naturally, the base cases are missing, but you can take it from here!